# Reset a array before subscribe angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am trying to use multiple filter in quick session i am getting the previous data in array along with the new data. How to remove the previous data.

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.vehicleAttribute = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('vehicleAttributes'));
  const data: ProductCatalogPostData = {
    vehicleModelAttributes: this.vehicleAttribute.vehicleModels[0].modelAttributes,
    role: 'vehicle owner',
    planType: this.planType
  };
  const page: ProductCatalogPostPagination = {
    page: this.pageNo
  };
  this.productCatalogService.compatibleProducts(data, page.page).subscribe(
    response => {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.products.length; i++) {
        this.lists.push(response.products[i]);
      }
      this.pageCount = response.totalCount;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

on filter function i am making try to make the list empty

```
onSelectedChange($event) {
  this.lists = [];
  this.planType = $event[0]
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

but i am still the previous subscribe data along with the new data. Any inputs is highly appreciated

Comment: Calling `ngOnInit` from the filter function is definitely not OK. You should never call it. The whole point is that Angular calls it.

Comment: Why would you expect different data? `productCatalogService.compatibleProducts` is likely going to return the same results regardless since you do not have any parameterization.

Comment: @AluanHaddad on `selectedChange` function i get the my `planType` value so i have call the http request with the new planType value. So that is reason i am calling `ngOnInit()` (please guide if there other way) and i do get different data on my planType value change. i used debounce function without any help

Comment: Instead of reusing the initialization logic and communicating by making changes to a mutable property in one method and just so that it can be read in another, extract the initialization logic into a separate method that takes `planType` as a parameter. Call the new method from both `ngOnInit` and `onSelectedChange`. You should make this change because the current approach you have is brittle and not obvious and is on the decidedly wrong side of code reuse by abusing the name of a framework hook, ngOnInit, for multiple purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **do** operator as below to achieve

```
this.productCatalogService.compatibleProducts(data, page.page)
  .do(data => {
       if(isEmpty(data)) {
          this.lists= new Array();
       }
   })
  .subscribe(response => {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.products.length; i++) {
        this.lists.push(response.products[i]);
      }
      this.pageCount = response.totalCount;
    },error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite get why are you iterating over, why just not

```
this.list = response.products
```

But if you have a reason not to do this way then you could copy elements by

```
this.list = [].concat(response.products)
```

all push them all at once if you for some reason do not want to clean

```
this.list.push(...response.products)
```

The last one will be equal to:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.list, response.products)
```

Comment: the reason why i am using push function is filter can i have pagination.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you are saying